# How to Bring a string on a new line to current line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text document with entries as:

```
cn=@exch 2010 oq test room,o=yyy,cn=users,dc=xxx,dc=local
uid=EXCH2010-TR
cn=bla bla,o=yyy,cn=users,dc=xxx,dc=local
uid=blabla

.....
```

I want to change it as:-

```
cn=@exch 2010 oq test room,o=yyy,cn=users,dc=xxx,dc=local || uid=EXCH2010-TR
cn=bla bla,o=yyy,cn=users,dc=xxx,dc=local || uid=blabla

...
```

What should be the expression in find+replace??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `\Ruid`
Replace with: `|| uid`

Where `\R`  means any combinations of `\n`, `\r`  or `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for the *Join Lines*  operation.  Select all of the lines, and then use Edit > Line Operations > Join Lines (Ctrl + J) to join them onto a single line.